# I'm not able to send response back to the client

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

I'm creating a server and a client. Right now I am able to send a message from the `Client` to the `ServerThread`, and the `ServerThread` is able to get the message. But when the `ServerThread` tries to respond back, the `Client` doesn't get the response, but the message was sent. It seems like it's waiting for the response, but is never able to receive it.

ServerThread:

```
public class ServerThread extends Thread {
   private Socket socket;
   private DataOutputStream outToClient;
   private BufferedReader inFromClient;

   public ServerThread(Socket socket) {
      try {
         System.out.println("Thread started");
         this.socket = socket;
         outToClient = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
         inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
      } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }

   public void run() {
      System.out.println("Thread running");
      try {
         System.out.println("ServerThread: " + inFromClient.readLine());
         outToClient.writeBytes("I Can help you");
      } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

Server:

```
public class Server {
   public static final int PORT = 5589;

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      ServerSocket socket;

      try {
         socket = new ServerSocket(5589);

         while (true)
            new ServerThread(socket.accept()).start();
      } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

Client:

```
public class Client {
   public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
      Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", App.PORT);
      BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
      PrintWriter outToServer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

      outToServer.println("Hello, I'm Lost");

      System.out.println(inFromServer.readLine()); //Hangs on this line

      socket.close();
   }
}
```

Comment: Try and `.flush()` after you have sent your data.

Comment: @fge haha that worked, you should put that as an answer. Thanks.

Comment: @HMarioD I had to wait couple minutes to accept an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data is buffered on the server side and not sent automatically until the buffer is full: you should `.flush()` on the server side after you `.writeBytes()` to ensure that it gets sent, even if you don't reach the buffer size (which is dependent on both the OS and the socket configuration).

Comment: So does this mean, I have to use `.flush()` every time I want to send data? Is there a better way of sending data?

Comment: There is: for instance you can create an `OutputStreamWriter` with autoflush on over the socket's OutputStream. Now, whether this is worth it is up to you.